# Get a list of date Ranges from a list Of dates

Tags: c#, linq, date-range

I am looking to get a list of date ranges (with Days) from a list of dates.

There may or may not be consecutive dates but there may be consistent gaps in the week range (i.e. All Mondays, Wednesdays and Thursdays OR ALL Mondays and Sundays, it can be any combination from 1 to 7 days of the week)

Example 1 - List of dates spanning 2 months that all fall on a Monday, Wednesday or Friday

```
ID  Date        Day
31  2016-02-01  Monday
31  2016-02-03  Wednesday
31  2016-02-05  Friday
31  2016-02-08  Monday
31  2016-02-10  Wednesday
31  2016-02-12  Friday
31  2016-02-15  Monday
31  2016-02-17  Wednesday
31  2016-02-19  Friday
31  2016-02-22  Monday
31  2016-02-24  Wednesday
31  2016-02-26  Friday
31  2016-02-29  Monday
31  2016-03-02  Wednesday
31  2016-03-04  Friday
31  2016-03-07  Monday
31  2016-03-09  Wednesday
31  2016-03-11  Friday
```

Goal - Identify that all dates follow a pattern - all dates fall on same days with no gaps

Desired output

```
ID                       31 
FROMDATE                 01/02/2016
TODATE                   11/03/2016
OPERATINGDAY_MONDAY      TRUE
OPERATINGDAY_TUESDAY     FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_WEDNESDAY   TRUE
OPERATINGDAY_THURSDAY    FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_FRIDAY      TRUE
OPERATINGDAY_SATURDAY    FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_SUNDAY      FALSE
```

Example 2 - Same as above but a gap in the middle (no Friday 19th) - split into 2 date ranges

```
ID  Date        Day
31  2016-02-01  Monday
31  2016-02-03  Wednesday
31  2016-02-05  Friday
31  2016-02-08  Monday
31  2016-02-10  Wednesday
31  2016-02-12  Friday
31  2016-02-15  Monday
31  2016-02-17  Wednesday
31  2016-02-22  Monday
31  2016-02-24  Wednesday
31  2016-02-26  Friday
31  2016-02-29  Monday
31  2016-03-02  Wednesday
31  2016-03-04  Friday
31  2016-03-07  Monday
31  2016-03-09  Wednesday
31  2016-03-11  Friday
```

Desired output is an object like this

```
ID                       31 
FROMDATE                 01/02/2016
TODATE                   17/02/2016
OPERATINGDAY_MONDAY      TRUE
OPERATINGDAY_TUESDAY     FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_WEDNESDAY   TRUE
OPERATINGDAY_THURSDAY    FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_FRIDAY      TRUE
OPERATINGDAY_SATURDAY    FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_SUNDAY      FALSE

ID                       31 
FROMDATE                 22/02/2016
TODATE                   11/03/2016
OPERATINGDAY_MONDAY      TRUE
OPERATINGDAY_TUESDAY     FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_WEDNESDAY   TRUE
OPERATINGDAY_THURSDAY    FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_FRIDAY      TRUE
OPERATINGDAY_SATURDAY    FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_SUNDAY      FALSE
```

Example 3 - Same as example 1 but a new date date/day in the middle (Tuesday 16th)

```
ID  Date        Day
31  2016-02-01  Monday
31  2016-02-03  Wednesday
31  2016-02-05  Friday
31  2016-02-08  Monday
31  2016-02-10  Wednesday
31  2016-02-12  Friday
31  2016-02-15  Monday
31  2016-02-16  Tuesday
31  2016-02-17  Wednesday
31  2016-02-22  Monday
31  2016-02-24  Wednesday
31  2016-02-26  Friday
31  2016-02-29  Monday
31  2016-03-02  Wednesday
31  2016-03-04  Friday
31  2016-03-07  Monday
31  2016-03-09  Wednesday
31  2016-03-11  Friday
```

Desired output is an object like this

```
ID                       31 
FROMDATE                 01/02/2016
TODATE                   15/02/2016
OPERATINGDAY_MONDAY      TRUE
OPERATINGDAY_TUESDAY     FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_WEDNESDAY   TRUE
OPERATINGDAY_THURSDAY    FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_FRIDAY      TRUE
OPERATINGDAY_SATURDAY    FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_SUNDAY      FALSE

ID                       31 
FROMDATE                 16/02/2016
TODATE                   16/02/2016
OPERATINGDAY_MONDAY      FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_TUESDAY     TRUE
OPERATINGDAY_WEDNESDAY   FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_THURSDAY    FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_FRIDAY      FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_SATURDAY    FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_SUNDAY      FALSE

ID                       31 
FROMDATE                 17/02/2016
TODATE                   11/03/2016
OPERATINGDAY_MONDAY      TRUE
OPERATINGDAY_TUESDAY     FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_WEDNESDAY   TRUE
OPERATINGDAY_THURSDAY    FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_FRIDAY      TRUE
OPERATINGDAY_SATURDAY    FALSE
OPERATINGDAY_SUNDAY      FALSE
```

A point in the right direction of how to attack this would be great. Preferably linq.

The end goal is to display the data in a coherent way

**Update**: Here is my code that I am currently using. I am handling consecutive days and non consecutive days but I am not sure where to even start with dates that follow a certain pattern. No doubt I am handling consecutive days all wrong.

```
foreach (var o in option.OptionPrices)
                {
                    var dateList = o.Dates.Select(d => d.Date).OrderBy(d => d.Date);
                    maxDate = (from d in dateList select d.Date).Max();
                    minDate = (from d in dateList select d.Date).Min();

                    if ((maxDate - minDate).Days + 1 == dateList.Count()) // runs everyday specified.
                    {
                        dateRange.Start = minDate;
                        dateRange.End = maxDate;
                        dateRange.OptionPriceid = o.OptionPriceId;
                        dateRange.OptionPriceName = o.Name;                        
                        dateRange.DayNames.Add("Monday");
                        dateRange.DayNames.Add("Tuesday");
                        dateRange.DayNames.Add("Wednesday");
                        dateRange.DayNames.Add("Thursday");
                        dateRange.DayNames.Add("Friday");
                        dateRange.DayNames.Add("Saturday");
                        dateRange.DayNames.Add("Sunday");

                        Pricing pricing = new Pricing
                        {
                            OptionId = option.OptionId,
                            OptionName = option.Name,
                            OptionPriceName = dateRange.OptionPriceName,
                            Fromdate = dateRange.Start.ToShortDateString(),
                            Todate = dateRange.End.ToShortDateString(),
                            AdultPrice = o.AdultPrice,
                            ChildPrice = o.ChildPrice,
                            InfantPrice = o.InfantPrice,
                            Operatingday_Monday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Monday") ? "x" : "-",
                            Operatingday_Tuesday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Tuesday") ? "x" : "-",
                            Operatingday_Wednesday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Wednesday") ? "x" : "-",
                            Operatingday_Thursday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Thursday") ? "x" : "-",
                            Operatingday_Friday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Friday") ? "x" : "-",
                            Operatingday_Saturday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Saturday") ? "x" : "-",
                            Operatingday_Sunday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Sunday") ? "x" : "-"
                        };

                        pricingModel.Add(pricing);

                        dateRange = new DateRange { DayNames = new List<string>() };                        
                        continue;
                    }

    // if we get to here we have non consecutive  dates 
                    foreach (var optionPriceDate in o.Dates.Select(d=>d.Date).OrderBy(d=>d.Date))
                    {                                                
                        currentDate = optionPriceDate;
                        if (dateRange.Start == DateTime.MinValue) // new range
                        {
                            dateRange.Start = currentDate; 
                            dateRange.OptionPriceid = o.OptionPriceId;
                            dateRange.OptionPriceName = o.Name;
                            if (!dateRange.DayNames.Contains(currentDate.DayOfWeek.ToString()))
                            {
                                dateRange.DayNames.Add(currentDate.DayOfWeek.ToString());
                            }                            
                            maxDate  = (from d in o.Dates select d.Date).Max(); 
                        }

                        if (currentDate == maxDate && (maxDate-lastDate).Days == 1 ) //last consecative day
                        {
                            dateRange.End = currentDate;
                            if (!dateRange.DayNames.Contains(currentDate.DayOfWeek.ToString()))
                            {
                                dateRange.DayNames.Add(currentDate.DayOfWeek.ToString());
                            }                     
                            Pricing pricing = new Pricing
                            {
                                OptionId = option.OptionId,
                                OptionName = option.Name,
                                OptionPriceName = dateRange.OptionPriceName,
                                Fromdate = dateRange.Start.ToShortDateString(),
                                Todate = dateRange.End.ToShortDateString(),
                                AdultPrice = o.AdultPrice,
                                ChildPrice = o.ChildPrice,
                                InfantPrice = o.InfantPrice,
                                Operatingday_Monday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Monday") ? "x" : "-",
                                Operatingday_Tuesday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Tuesday") ? "x" : "-",
                                Operatingday_Wednesday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Wednesday") ? "x" : "-",
                                Operatingday_Thursday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Thursday") ? "x" : "-",
                                Operatingday_Friday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Friday") ? "x" : "-",
                                Operatingday_Saturday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Saturday") ? "x" : "-",
                                Operatingday_Sunday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Sunday") ? "x" : "-"
                            };
                            pricingModel.Add(pricing);

                            // END of Price band - Rset everything
                            dateRange = new DateRange
                            {
                                Start = new DateTime(),
                                End = new DateTime(),
                                DayNames = new List<string>()
                            };
                            lastDate = DateTime.MinValue;
                            continue;
                        }



                        // Check to see if there is a gap
                        if ((currentDate.AddDays(-1) != lastDate) && lastDate != DateTime.MinValue)
                        {
                            dateRange.End = lastDate;

                            Pricing pricing = new Pricing
                            {
                                OptionId = option.OptionId,
                                OptionName = option.Name,
                                OptionPriceName = dateRange.OptionPriceName,
                                Fromdate = dateRange.Start.ToShortDateString(),
                                Todate = dateRange.End.ToShortDateString(),
                                AdultPrice = o.AdultPrice,
                                ChildPrice = o.ChildPrice,
                                InfantPrice = o.InfantPrice,
                                Operatingday_Monday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Monday") ? "x" : "-",
                                Operatingday_Tuesday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Tuesday") ? "x" : "-",
                                Operatingday_Wednesday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Wednesday") ? "x" : "-",
                                Operatingday_Thursday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Thursday") ? "x" : "-",
                                Operatingday_Friday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Friday") ? "x" : "-",
                                Operatingday_Saturday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Saturday") ? "x" : "-",
                                Operatingday_Sunday = dateRange.DayNames.Contains("Sunday") ? "x" : "-"
                            };
                            pricingModel.Add(pricing);                    

                            // Start New dateRange
                            dateRange = new DateRange
                            {
                                Start = currentDate,
                                End = new DateTime(),
                                OptionPriceid = o.OptionPriceId,
                                OptionPriceName = o.Name,
                                DayNames = new List<string>()
                            };
                            dateRange.DayNames.Add(currentDate.DayOfWeek.ToString());
                            lastDate = currentDate;
                            continue;                                                                           
                        }
                        if (!dateRange.DayNames.Contains(currentDate.DayOfWeek.ToString()))
                        {
                            dateRange.DayNames.Add(currentDate.DayOfWeek.ToString());
                        }   
                        lastDate = currentDate;
                    }                                        
                }
                PricingList = pricingModel;
```

Comment: If someone gonna do it with one LinQ query i'm going to buy him a beer :)

Comment: I under stand one linq query would be far fetched but taken the linq approach would the desired path :)

Comment: @stevenmahony, is it `linq to objects` or `linq to sql`?

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: SO is now Code OnDemand apparently; the point is to help you correct a problem, not come up with design and implementation for you. Do some code first, give it a shot... What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, not looking for someone to write the code, looking for an approach and the logic that would lend itself to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A LINQ solution would not be worth pursuing.  I would not want to maintain whatever lambda soup you might eventually build to pull out patterns. Hence, I went a bit OOP-y.

Here the Week is the thing. The patterns you appear to be looking for are based on the shape of week (ie, what days were operating).  Then the weeks that have the same shape can be strung together in Periods.

A week is made up of Days, and we indicate which ones had "work" (were operating). This makes it easy to see if two week have the same shape.

```
public class Week
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get { return Days.Keys.FirstOrDefault(); } }
    public DateTime EndDate { get { return Days.Keys.LastOrDefault(); } }
    public Dictionary<DateTime, bool> Days { get; private set; }

    public Week(DateTime startDate)
    {
        if (startDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
        {
            throw  new Exception("Week must start on Monday");
        }
        Days = new Dictionary<DateTime, bool>();
        for (int day = 0; day < 7; day++)
        {
            Days.Add(startDate.AddDays(day), false);
        }
    }
    public int Shape
    {
        get { return Days.Where(d => d.Value).Sum(d => (int)Math.Pow(2, (int)d.Key.DayOfWeek)); }
    }

    public bool AreAlike(Week otherWeek)
    {
        return this.Shape == otherWeek.Shape;
    }
    public void SetWorkDays(List<DateTime> workDays)
    {
        foreach (var workDay in workDays)
        {
            Days[Days.Keys.First(d => d.DayOfWeek == workDay.DayOfWeek)] = true;
        }
    }

    public void SetWorkDay(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, bool work = true)
    {
        Days[Days.Keys.First(d => d.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek)] = work;
    }
}
```

Then the list of the weeks can be turned into a list of periods that contain consecutive weeks with the same shape.

```
 public class Period
    {
        public List<Week> Weeks { get; private set; }

        public Period(Week week)
        {
            Weeks = new List<Week>(new[]{week});
        }

        public bool AddWeek(Week week)
        {
            if (!Weeks.First().AreAlike(week))
            {
                return false;
            }
            Weeks.Add(week);
            return true;
        }

        public DateTime StartDate 
        {
            get { return Weeks.First().StartDate; }
        }

        public DateTime EndDate
        {
            get { return Weeks.Last().EndDate; }
        }

        public Dictionary<DayOfWeek, bool> Display
        {
            get { return Weeks.First().Days.ToDictionary(d => d.Key.DayOfWeek, d => d.Value); }

        }
    }
```

Here's a factory to build the periods from a list of weeks...

```
public class PeriodFactory
    {
        public List<Period> GetPeriodsOfLikeWeeks(List<Week> weeks)
        {
            var periods = new List<Period>();
            Period currentPeriod = null;
            foreach (var week in weeks)
            {
                if (currentPeriod == null)
                {
                    currentPeriod = new Period(week);
                    periods.Add(currentPeriod);
                    continue;
                }
                if (!currentPeriod.AddWeek(week))
                {
                    currentPeriod = new Period(week);
                    periods.Add(currentPeriod);
                }
            }
            return periods;
        }
    }
```

And just for fun a WeekFactory that can be fed from your source data.

```
public class WeekFactory
    {
        public List<Week> BuildWeeksFromWorkDays(List<DateTime> workDays)
        {
            workDays = workDays.OrderBy(w => w).ToList();
            var startDate = workDays.First();
            if (startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                startDate = startDate.AddDays(-6);
            }
            else
            {
                startDate = startDate.AddDays((startDate.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday) * -1);
            }
            var weeks = new List<Week>();
            while (startDate <= workDays.Last())
            {
                var week = new Week(startDate);
                week.SetWorkDays( workDays.Where(d => d.Date >= startDate && d.Date < startDate.AddDays(7)).ToList());
                weeks.Add(week);
                startDate = startDate.AddDays(7);
            }
            return weeks;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi dbugger, apologies for the late reply. I can see what you are getting at here. I will take the premise of approaching this using weeks as my structure. I will attempt it and reply with my updated code. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Hi dbugger, I've run through your solution to get an understanding of it. It does exactly what I need, I cant add anything to it. I would never have come up with this. So I appreciate your answer and I will favorite this as there are a few code snippets in here that I really like and would never have used before. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @stevenmahony Glad to help -- it was a fun problem to think through.

Comment: Using the Shape property on the Week object, genius.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not the full answer to your problem as you probably are using a database at the back. So much tweaking and such will be needed to get it correct for your own usage.

But here goes... my answer i wrote using LinqPad just for fun and beer ;-) (OP didn't state Linq2Sql specifically)

Little explanation. Group the dates by weeknumber according to a certain calendar and weekstart algoritm. Then from each group build results about that week.

This example only shows part of the answer as you still need to iterate over each result and determine if you need to combine successive records which are equal in operating day.

```
void Main()
{

    var data = new [] { 
        new Record(31, DateTime.Parse("2016-02-01")),
        new Record(31, DateTime.Parse("2016-02-03")),
        new Record(31, DateTime.Parse("2016-02-05")),
        new Record(31, DateTime.Parse("2016-02-08")),
        new Record(31, DateTime.Parse("2016-02-10")),
        new Record(31, DateTime.Parse("2016-02-12")),
        new Record(31, DateTime.Parse("2016-02-15")),
        new Record(31, DateTime.Parse("2016-02-16")),
        new Record(31, DateTime.Parse("2016-02-17")),
        new Record(31, DateTime.Parse("2016-02-22")),
        new Record(31, DateTime.Parse("2016-02-24")),
        new Record(31, DateTime.Parse("2016-02-26")),
        new Record(31, DateTime.Parse("2016-02-29")),
        new Record(31, DateTime.Parse("2016-03-02")),
        new Record(31, DateTime.Parse("2016-03-04")),
        new Record(31, DateTime.Parse("2016-03-07")),
        new Record(31, DateTime.Parse("2016-03-09")),
        new Record(31, DateTime.Parse("2016-03-11"))
    };

    (
        from rec in data
        group rec by new { ID = rec.Id,  WeekNum = new GregorianCalendar().GetWeekOfYear(rec.Date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday)} into g
        select new { 
            ID = g.Key.ID, 
            FromDate = g.First().Date, 
            LastDate = g.Last().Date,
            OPERATINGDAY_MONDAY = (g.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday) != null),
            OPERATINGDAY_TUESDAY = (g.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday) != null),
            OPERATINGDAY_WEDNESDAY = (g.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday) != null),
            OPERATINGDAY_THURSDAY = (g.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday) != null),
            OPERATINGDAY_FRIDAY = (g.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday) != null),
            OPERATINGDAY_SATURDAY = (g.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) != null),
            OPERATINGDAY_SUNDAY = (g.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) != null),
        }
    ).Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class Record
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    public string Day {get;set;}

    public Record (int id, DateTime date)
    {
        Id = id;
        Date = date;
    }
}
```